# Find the indices of elements which are larger than 10 in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `a`, which consists of some positive real numbers. I want to find the indices of elements which are larger than 10 in list `a`, and put the indices into another list `index`. The following is my code:

```
a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};
index = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[a], i++,
 If[a[[i]] > 10, index = Append[index, i]]
]
index
```

The output is

```
{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

which is correct. Is there a better way to find the list `index`? For example, do not use the `For` loop. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Position[a, _?(# > 10 &)]` . If you start at 1, if 0 just subtract 1

Comment: Thank you for your comment. :-)

Comment: @JasonB Thank you for your comment. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Pick` and `UnitStep` as follows:

```
index = Pick[Range[Length[a]], UnitStep[10 - a], 0]
```